# How to remove the underscore from Android Text input?

Tags: android, css, typescript

I am currently developing a multi-platformed app for use on IOS/Android/Windows phone.

I am trying to create a 'themed' text input, where all buttons/inputs/text look identical throughout all aspects of the devices by using DevExtreme (typescript).

I have almost completed it, although below shows my problem with android:

[image: A sample input for android]

This shows a blue 'underscore' on text input. For my system, this is NOT wanted.

Is there a way of editing my css file as to force remove this from the android platform?

I have previously tried removing the text decoration:

```
text-decoration: none;
```

But this did not work.

Anyone got any ideas/solutions to remove this?

Some of my **css** file so far:

```
[type=text]{
     padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
  border-color:none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: #585757;
color:#cfcfcf;
}
[type=text]:focus{ 

    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1); 
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: #585757;
color:#cfcfcf;
}

[type=text]:active{
    margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;   

    border-color: blue;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px blue;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px blue;
            box-shadow: 0 0 8px blue;

            -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: #585757;
color:#cfcfcf;

}
```

Is there an element to remove this from an android device?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it bey setting the Background Drawable of the EditText to null

```
editText.setBackgroundDrawable(null)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this css styles to say to the all links without underline

```
A:link {text-decoration: none}
A:visited {text-decoration: none}
A:active {text-decoration: none}
```

Comment: it's not a link though. Plus as stated in the question, i've already tried that before!